# While loop to change object property in php

Tags: php, class, while-loop, this

i got this while loop into my listByEvent function inside my foto class to retrieve my db fotos:

```
    while ($fetch_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_foto)) {

        $this -> idFoto = $fetch_query['idFoto'];
        $this -> arquivo = $fetch_query['arquivo'];
        $this -> legenda = $fetch_query['legenda'];
        $this -> idEvento = $fetch_query['idEvento'];
        $this -> curtidas = $fetch_query['curtidas'];
        $this -> naocurtidas = $fetch_query['naocurtidas'];
        $fotos[] = $this;

    }
             return $fotos;
```

Then in my view (show.php), i call the method like this:

```
                $foto = new foto();
                $foto -> idEvento = $key -> idEvento;
                $fotos = $foto -> listByEvent();
                foreach ($fotos as $fotokey) {
                                    //here i proper format the layout
                                     }
```

But the while loop can`t override the $this properties and it retrieves always the same foto. If i change the fc to call a new obj, like this:

```
            while ($fetch_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_foto)) {

        $jack = new foto();
        $jack -> idFoto = $fetch_query['idFoto'];
        $jack -> arquivo = $fetch_query['arquivo'];
        $jack -> legenda = $fetch_query['legenda'];
        $jack -> idEvento = $fetch_query['idEvento'];
        $jack -> curtidas = $fetch_query['curtidas'];
        $jack -> naocurtidas = $fetch_query['naocurtidas'];
        $fotos[] = $jack;

    }
            return $fotos;
```

Than it works. Anyone can explain why i cant override this methods on a while loop? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

When you assign class objects, you don't make a copy, you're just assigning a reference to the object. So in your first loop, all the array elements refer to the same `$this` object, which you modify each time through the loop. You need to use `new` to create new objects so that the array elements will be distinct.

Comment: Thank you. You mean that in the $fotos[] = $this, every key will change everytime $this change and get all the same values?

Comment: Yes, they all get the same values, because there's just one `$this` object in a particular method call.

Answer (score 0):

The **this** pointer is a pointer accessible only within the  **nonstatic** member functions of a class, struct, or union type. It points to the object for which the member function is called. **Static** member functions do not have a this pointer.

Hence **this** pointer is returning the same value.

So you need create a new object to hold the values. That's why its working in second loop.

Comment: It`s not a static function, it`s been called on the obj, like obj -> ListByid(). If it was a static function, it won`t return nothing from the first looping (i will get a can`t call obj properties on static function method error).